# Prevent YouTube API full screen on PhoneGap Android

Tags: javascript, cordova, youtube-javascript-api

I’m working with the YouTube API via JavaScript in my PhoneGap app, and I’ve successfully got the video to play using an event handler. But how do I stop the video from playing in fullscreen on a android? I have a snippet of my code below:

```
var player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '240',
    width: '240',
    events:{
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
});
function onPlayerReady(){
    document.getElementById('play_vid').onclick = function(){
        player.loadVideoById('VID-ID');
        player.playVideo();
    }
}
```

When I look into Google Console debugger, I see that the YouTube API automtically puts an `allowfullscreen` attribute to the frame tag. But when I dynamically remove this, it still goes to full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the **fs** var to **0** ?

`var player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '240',
    width: '240',
    playerVars: { fs: 0 },
    events:{
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
});`

Check here for more settings https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo